# Interpreting an odds ratio from Poisson regression with multiple levels

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, odds-ratio

If I have a poisson regression like so:

`glm(freq ~ Category, df, family='poisson'`

The `category` variable contains about 10 levels. If I take the `exp(coef)` and get the odds ratio. How can I properly interpret them for count data like this?

Assume the following ORs:

```
DWI 1.55
Assualt  10
Theft 122
```

Is it safe to say that the odds of a theft happening are 122 more likely then not happening? I understand that OR are the likelihood of the odds increasing by some factor. But what is that some factor here with one variable and many levels?

Comment: You are probably using a log link function and not a logit link function, so the exponentiated coefficients are incidence rate ratios not odds ratios.

Comment: ah alright, then how could I interpret those numbers as a rate ratio?

Comment: For PoisReg, you would need multiple crimes, each represented with yes/no (1,0) and then some exposure variable (yes/no).   Then, $\exp(\beta_{exposure})$ would be the total relative risk, $RR$, of being exposed -- which would be used as a constant multiple for the fitted crime rate for each of the crimes.  Exposure could be e.g. (felon/not a felon).